# How to switch to new scene? Attached the JavaFX code I am working with:

Tags: javafx, scene, stage

I would like to have a switch to new JavaFX scene/ new class called: TwoScene. 
This stage(code) works well. But clicking on "sending" button, nothing happens! I would like setOnAction to launch new class in which I would like to create brandnew scene...

```
public class InsertingClass {
    private Stage stage = new Stage();
    private VBox veenaidud;
    private Button sending;
    private Button logOut;
    private HashMap<String, String> data;

    InsertingClass(Integer user_id) {       
        teavitus = new Label();
        windowCurrent();
        setupMinuAndmed();
        setupLogout();
        sendingToNewSwitch();
    }

    private void windowCurrent() {
        data = naidud.saaEelmisedNaidud(kasutaja_id);
        sending = new Button("NEXT");  
        logOut = new Button("Logout");

        veenaidud.getChildren().addAll(puuAndmed, soevesi, raadiusnait, kulmvesi, kulmnait, sending, logOut);
        stage.setScene(veenait);
        stage.show();
    }


    private void sendingToNewSwitch() {
        sending.setOnAction(event -> {
            new TwoScene();
            stage.close();
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the code TwoScene:

```
public class TwoScene {

public Stage thestage = new Stage();
Button btnscene1, btnscene2;
Label lblscene1, lblscene2;
FlowPane pane1, pane2;
Scene scene1, scene2;

public void opens() {

    btnscene1 = new Button("Button: to the page - 2"); 
    btnscene2 = new Button("Button: to the page - 1");
    btnscene1.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
    btnscene2.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
    lblscene1 = new Label("1. Select the type");
    lblscene2 = new Label("2. Select size");
    btnscene1.setPrefSize(300, 20);
    btnscene2.setPrefSize(170, 100);  


    pane1=new FlowPane();  
    pane2=new FlowPane();
    pane1.setVgap(50);
    pane2.setVgap(50);
    pane1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tan;-fx-padding: 10px;");     
    pane2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;-fx-padding: 10px;");

    ToggleGroup g = new ToggleGroup();          
    RadioButton p1 = new RadioButton("Choice 1: VAHER");
    RadioButton p2 = new RadioButton("Choice 2: MÄND");
    RadioButton p3 = new RadioButton("Choice 3: TAMM");
    p1.setToggleGroup(g);
    p2.setToggleGroup(g);
    p3.setToggleGroup(g);
    p3.setSelected(true);
    Slider slider = new Slider();
    slider.setMin(0);
    slider.setMax(100);
    slider.setValue(40);
    slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
    slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
    slider.setMajorTickUnit(50);

    pane1.getChildren().addAll(lblscene1, btnscene1, p1, p2, p3); 
    pane2.getChildren().addAll(lblscene2, btnscene2, slider);

    //g.getSelectedToggle(); to DEVELOP HOW TO SAVE USER DATA FROM THE CHOICE


    scene1 = new Scene(pane1, 400, 200);  //type
    scene2 = new Scene(pane2, 200, 400);  //slider 

    thestage.setTitle("Headline: lets review it!");
    thestage.setScene(scene1);
    //thestage.setScene(menuContentFrame); //HP....
    thestage.show();
}

public void ButtonClicked(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource()==btnscene1)
        thestage.setScene(scene2);
    else
        thestage.setScene(scene1);
}
```

}

Comment: Show us `TwoScene` class code. If your `TwoScene` class extends `Scene` and you only want to switch scenes in current `Stage` just set new scene to stage. Use `stage.setScene(new TwoScene());` If you want to open new window then create new stage, set TwoScene to it and close old stage.

Comment: Hey, wow, thanks for the reply. I would like to create new stage (including some new features), yes, that should also close the old stage. I added the code of TwoScene (above).

Comment: Here is my code (currently I have some unexpected problem to enter! Using name/password taken from the SQLite database, also written at the Login: https://github.com/refocusdevelop/calcTreeYear/tree/master/calcTreeYear/javaFXvaheetapp/src

Comment: In `InsertingClass` you only create new instance of TwoScene but never invoke `opens()` method. Move code from `opens()` to default constructor or call that method `new TwoScene().opens();` in `sendingToNewSwitch()`. Tip: don't use upper case in methods name, change `ButtonClicked(ActionEvent e)` to `buttonClicked(ActionEvent e)`

Comment: to MBec: yes, it worked well adding this kind method calling! Thank you very very much!